# Where should I post a question about making dynamic signatures?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where would I post a question related to how to make a dynamic signature. It involves, web applications, coding, graphics.

I posted in web applications, and the question was closed. Where should I post it?

Comment: Your question over there is lacking a detail: what signature on/to **what**? It's not clear at all in what context that signature would be used.

Comment: To begin with, no one is likely to know for sure what you mean by 'dynamic signature'. A particularly energetic bit of handwriting? A frequency signature? Something else?

Comment: True but I explained it in the post.

Comment: Not in this post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear which forum you are using (I don't know whether each forum uses the same format).

Also the signature comes down to some sort of html and embed problem.

See these questions [tagged signature](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signature) to see an example of what can kind of [signature] questions Web Applications accept.

As long as your question is about how to use a feature of an application, it *should* be on-topic. Forums are more in the gray area. I have opened a meta topic on Web Applications to ask others,

[Should internet forums be treated as off-topic?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1036/should-internet-forums-be-treated-as-off-topic)

*Next time you should also post in the **site** meta, so that the mods of that site can track your problem. meta.stackoverflow does not cover all SE network site topic activities*

<sub>I am a moderator for Web Applications Stack Exchange</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Currently, nowhere.

You need to narrow down your question.  Work at your problem until you have *one*  **specific** problem.  Then it should be easy to determine where it goes.

Also, you need more details.  We can help you much better if we know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes it would be nice to be that far but I don't even know where to start on it.

Comment: @Fogest Google is your friend.  :)